# Deselect range after autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, deselect

This seems incredibly simple and straight forward, but no matter how much testing and searching I do I am unable to resolve. I currently have scripting that turns on AutoFilter without selecting anything, but I thought I could copy the data and paste into a new worksheet without the data being selected. However, after it completes the action it does show columns A:K as selected. I have been unable to figure out how to deselect those columns on the worksheet nor have I been able to find out how to copy and paste without them being selected in the first place. Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub RunScript()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Sheets.Add.Name = "copy"
Dim galreqws As Worksheet
Set galreqws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("copy")

Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A:K").AutoFilter

ws1.Range("A1:K1000").Copy Destination:=Sheets("copy").Range("A1:K1000")

galreqws.Delete

'Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A:K").AutoFilter
Range("A:K").Select
Sheets("Buttons").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Application.CutCopyMode=False ?

Comment: Where would I place that addition? I edited the above to include the full script if that helps.

Comment: Try after display alerts and right before ending set it back to true.

Comment: Also do you need Range("A:K").select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally bad practice to use `.Select` unless you really intend the user to see a selected range. As far as I know there are no actions where `.Select` is required.

The following is a suggestion of a few things you could do to improve your code:

```
Sub RunScript()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet
    Set wsCurrent = ActiveSheet

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    Dim wsGalreq As Worksheet
    ' Note that .Add will activate the new sheet so we'll
    ' need to reactivate the worksheet that was previously active
    'Set wsGalreq = Worksheets.Add
    'wsGalreq.Name = "copy"
    Set wsGalreq = Worksheets("copy")

    wsData.Range("A:K").AutoFilter 1, "Supplier A"
    ' Find the used range in columns A to K and copy over starting
    ' at cell A1 of wsGalreq
    Intersect(wsData.UsedRange, wsData.Range("A:K")).Copy Destination:=wsGalreq.Range("A1")

    ' Doubt deleting the new sheet was intentional?
    ' wsGalreq.Delete

    ' Now change the view to the desired worksheet, uncomment one:
    'Worksheets("Buttons").Select
    'wsCurrent.Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, I really appreciate it. I am just really in the learning stages of VBA so appreciate learning how better to write the code.

Comment: Question @snoopen, I tried running the above script but it gave me an error almost immediately that said "Object required." When I debug it, it highlights the below line:


    Set wsCurrent = ActiveWorksheet

Comment: Oh sorry, that should have been `Set wsCurrent = ActiveSheet` I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hopefully one last question @snoopen, using this Intersect method how would I search/select a specific record like "Supplier A" instead of doing it using the Autofilter method. Thanks again, really appreciate all the help.

Comment: I've updated the question to show how to filter column 1 with AutoFilter. To do it **without** AutoFilter try this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f5969073d58dd4e84192

Comment: The script you provided for how to do it without autofilter worked like a charm. It operates so much quicker it seems, its no wonder people advise using that instead of autofilter when able. Quick question, is there a way to use that method and search for 2 different criteria in 2 different columns? i.e. "Supplier A" in column A and "Manufacturing" in column B? Thanks again for all your help. @snoopen

Comment: I actually figured it out on my own by simply adding a AND rngData.Cells(i, 7).Value = "xxxx" Then command. I originally tried it with a "&" instead of "AND" but it didn't work. Any chance someone can tell me the different between "&" and "AND" in VBA? Thanks again.

Comment: Nice work, exactly what I would have recommended. The difference between & and AND is that & only joins strings. AND is the logical operator. http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Operators-And-Functions.html

Comment: I am running into some issues trying to use a wildcard in our existing code. I had assumed if I did something like this: If rngData.Cells(i, 11).Value = "Supplier A" And rngData.Cells(i, 6).Value = "*RAIL*" Then however it didn't seem to pull any data that has RAIL in the text. Any ideas @snoopen ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line below from your code.

```
Range("A:K").Select
```